# In Android DataBase i Got This Error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "+": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, database, android-database

Hello I Got This Error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "+" syntax error (code 1) , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbl_Individual_Donor_Registration WHERE BloodGroup = B+

Here Is My Code For Table Elements:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BLOOD_PROJECT";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_Individual_Donor_Registration";
public static final String TABLE_NAME_BLOOD_BANK = "tbl_Blood_Bank_Registration";
public static final String COL_1 = "Id";
public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
public static final String COL_3 = "Password";
public static final String COL_4 = "BloodGroup";
public static final String COL_5 = "BloodQuantity";
public static final String COL_6 = "MobileNo";
```

Here Is Code For My Actual Select Query:

```
    String select = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " = "+ final_blood_group;
```

And The final_blood_group is Come From The Spinner Value which is came from the user's Selection i hope you will Help me Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need change little thing in code.Sample here

correct code should like this

```
   SELECT * FROM tbl_Individual_Donor_Registration WHERE BloodGroup = 'B+'//you need single quote in B+
```

so you need to put single quote in

```
final_blood_group="'B+'";
```

then your code look like this

SELECT * FROM tbl_Individual_Donor_Registration WHERE BloodGroup = 'B+'

if you put without single then work as keyowrd.

Comment: Hello You Cannot Understand My Problem the B+ is Came Dynamically And You Will Provide The Static Solution Please Provide Me Dynamic Solution Thank You.

Comment: String select = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " = "+ " '" + final_blood_group + "' " ;

Comment: copy this line  and try it

Comment: in this line i used single quote.

Comment: i just tried but it will show me Error:  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbl_Individual_Donor_Registration WHERE BloodGroup = B+'

Comment: String select = "SELECT * FROM  " + TABLE_NAME + "  WHERE  " + COL_4 + "  =  ' "+ final_blood_group + " ' " ;

Comment: above code I have not used space .this code may work.

Comment: In first solution you can see last single quote has but error at first single quote.

Comment: now  I am working other things, so I cant check .else I rectify manually.